# Circle functions and its fibres

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How can i formally deduce from the definition of homotopy that if a circle function $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is homotopic to the n-th power function $z \mapsto z^n$, then its mapping wraps around $S^1$ $n$ times.

I want to use this to then easly show that $|f^{-1}(z)| \geq |n|$ for all $z \in S^1.$

Comment: First you need to give us your definition of "wraps around $S^1$ $n$ times". Btw no, it does not follow that $|f'(z)|\ge n$ for all $z\in S^1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich it *is* true that $|f^{-1}(z)|\ge|n|$...

Comment: $|f^{-1}(z)|$ refers to the number of elements in the inverse image of $z$.  @DavidC.Ullrich